# Density of a Probability measure with respect to an equivalent one

Tags: probability-theory

Let $\mathbb{P_1}$ and $\mathbb{P_2}$ be two equivalent measures and $Z=d\mathbb{P_1}/d\mathbb{P_2}$ the density of $\mathbb{P_1}$ with respect to $\mathbb{P_2}$. Prove:

1) Uniqueness of Z up to $\mathbb{P_2}$-null sets,

2) $Z>0$ $\mathbb{P_2}$ almost surely,

3) $X \in L^{1}(\mathbb{P_1})$ if and only if $XZ \in L^{1}(\mathbb{P_2})$ and in this case $\mathbb{E_1}(X) = \mathbb{E_2}(XZ)$

4) $1/Z$ is the density of $\mathbb{P_2}$ with respect to $\mathbb{P_1}$

My approach for part 1) would be: let $Z_1$ and $Z_2$ two of those, then $Z_1=Z_2$ leads to $d\mathbb{P_1}/d\mathbb{P_2}=d\mathbb{P_1}/d\mathbb{P_2}$ and $d\mathbb{P_1}d\mathbb{P_2}=d\mathbb{P_1}d\mathbb{P_2}$ but I don't know how to interpret this expression.  I think it has something to do with the radon nykodim derivative. Can you help me to understand this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am going to switch $\mathbb P_1$ and $\mathbb P_2$ to $\mu$ and $\nu$ for convenience.

By hypothesis, $\mu$ and $\nu$ are mutually absolutely continuous positive, finite measures.

The R-N theorem gives us that $\mu(E)=\int_EZd\nu,\ $ where $Z$ is as in the question.  Now $Z\ge 0$ because the measures are positive, and if $Z_1$ satisfies the same condition as $Z$, then for all $\nu$-measurable sets $E$, we have $\int_EZd\nu=\int_EZ_1d\nu\Rightarrow \int_E |Z-Z_1|d\nu=0\Rightarrow Z=Z_1$ a.e.$\ \nu$.

Suppose $Z=0$ on a set $E$ of positive $\nu$-measure. Then, $\mu(E)=\int_EZd\nu=0$. On the other hand, $\nu\ll \mu$ so $\nu(E)=0$, which is a contradiction. Thus, $Z>0\ $ a.e. $\nu$.

Now, $d\mu=Zd\nu\Rightarrow \int_EXd\mu=\int_EXZd\nu$ for any $X\in L^1(\mu)$. (To see this, verify the formula for characteristic functions, then it will be true for simple functions and finally, apply the MCT to conclude). This shows that $XZ\in L^1(\nu)\Leftrightarrow X\in L^1(\mu).$

Finally, we have a R-N derivative $W$ for $\nu:\ \nu(E)=\int_EWd\mu.$ But also, by the remarks in the previous paragraph, $\int_E\frac{1}{Z}d\mu=\int_E\frac{1}{Z}\cdot Zd\nu\Rightarrow \nu(E)=\int_E\frac{1}{Z}d\mu$ and the uniqueness result of the first paragraph implies that $W=1/Z$ a.e.$\mu$. Note: $1/Z\in L^1(\mu)$ because $1/Z>0$ a.e. $\mu$ (use the same argument as that for $Z$.)

Comment: thank you for your fast answer! In part 3 i don't get why it is $d\mu = Zd\nu$. Then, I understand that your proof shows the equality of the expected value, but why is this enough to prove the $L^{1}$ belonging condition?

Comment: $d\mu=Zd\nu$ is shorthand for $\mu(E)=\int_EZd\nu.$ If $XZ\in L^1(\nu)$, then since $X$ is assumed $\mu-$measurable, there are simple functions $X_n\uparrow X.$ Then, using the formula on $X_n$ and the MCT, we get $\int X=\lim \int X_n=\lim \int X_nZ=\int XZ$. Thus, $X\in L^1(\mu).$

Comment: from the second to the third equality in the last row: from where does the $Z$ come from? And what is the definition of "beeing in $L^{1}(\mu)$" ? (i thought it was the integral of the absolute value beeing finite)

Comment: the $Z$ comes from the formula in step three, applied to the $X_n,$  which are $L^1$ because they are simple and the measures are finite